# HTML select option to be captured from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been spending days to get over this but no luck.

I have a html page in Google script whereby I want a dropdown list - this is achieved as follows

```
<div>
<select name="source">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Now instead of the manual inputs I want the option fields to be captured from a spreadsheet, if the coloumn range increase or decrease the dropdown list should update accordingly.

Any workarounds please...

Regards,

Comment: What all have you tried? Sample code of your issue would definitely help in establishing where a potential error is occurring. Especially with the answer below seems to be what your are looking for. Just whenever you get the data range it queries how many objects are in that specific column. The drop-down won't instantly change when the info is changed and will only change when refreshed or on command through the UI.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/1916/ here is the code I use, this gives a list of contents on from the sheet, but how to add them to dropdown?? Sorry I'm still a novice.

Comment: if I use only data[i][j] without select, it gives the list required but how to add them to the dropdown list.....(comment added to aviod confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the elements in the array instead of the array object itself, you need to include the DATA array inside Scriptlet tags.And I see no requirement to use a 2-dimensional array. The correct syntax should be:

```
<?
 var sheet   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(0Avt7ejriwlxudGZfV2xJUGJZLXktQ2RhQU1ugtgtaXc").getSheetByName("MRF Tab");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("C3:C"+lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  ?>
<div>
  <select>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
      <option><?!= data[i] ?></option>
    <? } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

And its really a bad idea to mix *data-fetching code* & *html UI* code within a template. You should use **separate gs** and **html files** & apply the optimizations as [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) has suggested.

Comment: It gives me the following error "Invalid script or HTML content: HtmlOutput:4+1 - 2: Unexpected token <." http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/1917  (Note: I'm including the javascript in between <script> tag...

Comment: Well, it works perfectly for me. Take a look at this: App: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx25-nlt380BcRTqvADFag8ov9GXK2QYV08I-1LlWgn2M6tahRs/exec Sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak8UXE3yTEiQdFJRMS1yTkpHLTE1NmZsaXdhVnhIQUE&usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please share the workbook as "Can Edit" I assume it isnt, so that I can go and check the script editor. Looks like you are bringing some releif...

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted...but if I go to either Script editor or Script Manager, there are no codes visible...how can I view the codes behind it...Special thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't be possible as this code is embedded to a site which belongs to my college domain & I don't have permission to share it with outsiders.

Comment: Ok, if you can share some screenshots of the script editor...I might get some idea on it...

Comment: I have modified the code to work properly in a spreadsheet. You can now access the code from the Script Editor. The UI can be triggered using the "OPEN" option under the "DIALOG" menu

Answer (score 3):

This is an adaptation of the technique demonstrated in the [Html Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates) documentation.

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('DynamicList');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);

  return htmlOutput;
}

function getListOptions() {
  // In production code, get an array of options by
  // reading a spreadsheet.
  var options = ['Saab','Opel','Audi'];

  return( options );
}
```

#### DynamicList.html

```
<div>
  <select id="optionList">
    <option>Loading...</option>    
  </select>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
      .getListOptions();
});

function buildOptionList(options) {
  var list = $('#optionList');
  list.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    list.append('<option value="' + options[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do I map this to spreadsheet, should I use the spreadsheet link in place of "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"

Comment: Note the comment in `getListOptions()` in Code.gs, that's where you should read the options from your spreadsheet. The options should be `return`ed as an array of values, to be compatible with the javascript function in the html.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the documentation, specifically, [Pushing section variables to templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-templates?hl=es#pushing_variables_to_templates), insurance can be useful.