# populating dropdown list values from google spreadsheet using HTML service

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-select

Hi I am trying to get a dropdown list using html and google script.
The values for the list should be populated from a google spreadsheet.  After searching a lot on stackoverflow I managed the below code.  But I am still not able to get the data from spreadsheet as dropdown option.  There is no error but i am just getting a blank dropbox as output

Spreadsheet link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaxzTWRf4_xDhfkf-_S9Zr2m-M-9blOcpFBt4JyT5do/edit#gid=0

### code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  return htmlOutput;
}
```

### html code

```
< select id = "something" > < option > Choose a option < /option>
</select > < body onload = "addList()" > < /body>
<script>
function addList(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qaxzTWRf4_xDhfkf-_S9Zr2m-M-9blOcpFBt4JyT5do').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + lastRow);
  var options = new Array()
  var select = document.getElementById("something");
  var data = myRange.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
    options.push(data[i]);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    var el = document
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
  }
</script >
```

Comment: look at the htmlService official docs. you are mixing client with server code which will never work. the docs explain well how to do this (to call a server function from the client side, or to include the data as part of the template)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML select option to be captured from Google Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788437/html-select-option-to-be-captured-from-google-spreadsheet)