# google apps script html select options loaded from spreadsheet data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

New to google apps scripting, javascript, etc...

Trying to create a sidebar in a spreadsheet that contains an html select object that is populated from a column in one of the sheets.

I've tried using code that I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788437/html-select-option-to-be-captured-from-google-spreadsheet), but the function to load the options doesn't appear to be executing when the html is loaded.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

code in code.gs:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('USD Conversion')
      .addItem('Convert Dollars to Foreign Currency', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Load rates from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  var addCountriesMenuEntries = [{name: "Add Countries", functionName: "addCountries"}];
  var conversionEntries = [{name: "Convert Dollars for Foreign Currency", functionName: "showSidebar"}];
}

/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var template = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar')

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('USD Conversion')
      .setWidth(400);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}

function getListOptions() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CountryCodes");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("P2:P"+lastRow); 
  var countries = myRange.getValues(); 

  return( countries );
}
```

code in Sidebar.html:

```
<div class="labels">
    <p>Destination Country:</p>
</div>

<div>
  <select name="optionList">
    <option>Loading...</option>    
  </select>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
    $(function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
            .getListOptions();
    });

    function buildOptionList(countries) {
        var list = $('#optionList');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            list.append(countries[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reference your select list in jQuery by id, the select element needs an id attribute `<select id="optionList" name="optionList">`. To add an option to an option list, you can use the following syntax: `list.append(new Option(countries[i],countries[i]));` where the fist value is the name and the second is the value.

You Google Script code looks good but you could add `Logger.log(countries);` right before your return statement to validate that you are returning the expected results. Within your Google Script editor, you can test a function by clicking Run -> (function name) than click View -> Logs to view the logs. It's best to test your Google Script code and HTML code separately before trying to use them together.